# #1045 - Access denied for user 'a7178301_Burea'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, host

actually i am just hosting php myadmin server.i am entering my credientiality that is correct then also it give this error. i don't know any thing about php. i have just created account at 000webhost and then in action i have followed through **GOTOCVPANEL**  after in database phpmyadmin . created password and entering it after 2 minute then also this happen. please guide me .
Welcome to phpMyAdmin 2.11.4

> Error 1045 - Access denied for user 'a7178301_Burea'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>    Language Info

Comment: shouldn't it be the IP of the sql server and not localhost? maybe the php server does not host the sql server itself?

Comment: then how to host only php my admin on the server

Comment: No when they send you the sign up email, they send an IP for the sql server. Replace localhost in your code with that ip. I could be wrong but that's the only explanation I have atm

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using "localhost" to connect.
The name of the database is that appears in your control panel.

ex: mysql15.000webhost.com

check this:

http://www.000webhost.com/forum/web-programming/31247-access-denied-user-username-localhost-using-password-yes.html

Comment: but i am not writting any single line of code just gone through cvpanel in 000webhost created database and then just open phpadminpanel

Comment: checkout http://www.000webhost.com/forum/customer-assistance/17619-cant-login-phpmyadmin-my-db.html . From what i have read i think it is an issue with your provider. Please contact them or go to any of their forums.